# PHP: Unintentional multidimensional array insted of onedimenisonal

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm searching 1 column in 1 table of my database for different entries by using this statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table WHERE column entry LIKE '%keyword%'
```

This works fine since dumping the mysqli_query shows me the expected amount of entries for the specific keyword provided.
I then try to write the query result into a onedimensional array (the array is declared somewhere else in the code):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {
$array[] = $row;
}
```

As a result I'm expecting a simple numeric onedimensional array like this:

```
Array(
[0] => value 1
[1] => value 2
...
)
```

When checking the result by using print_r($array) I get an array like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Array([0] => value1)
[1] => Array([0] => value2)
...
)
```

I don't know where this weird structure comes from since this is not the only array in my code. I checked the particular code block step by step and came to the conclusion that the problem is within the creation of the array. Using mysqli_fetch_assoc didn't solve this issue. But what exactly is the problem here?

Has anyone ever seen something like this and any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: side node: Instead of using `while(mysqli_fetch_row()){....}` just to generate a full array, you should use `$array = $result->fetch_all();` which is about 30% faster. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: @bear87 Deciding to use `fetch_all()` or not depends solely on if you are going to iterate the data "in the same layer/script" (this is mentioned in http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)  Basically, to offer best practices, we'd need to know what you are doing next with the data.  Are you merely transferring this data to another place, or are you just displaying to screen? are you imploding the data? with what?  Feel free to provide feedback so that I can be more informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mysqli_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) returns an array of the columns in the SQL, so when you add it to the array...

```
$array[] = $row;
```

This will create an array of each row - which is the array of arrays.  If instead you add the column value to the array...

```
$array[] = $row[0];
```

This should give the result your after.

Answer (score 1):

[`mysqli_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) gets a result row as an enumerated array. Other than *Nigel Ren*'s approach, you can also use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). It will fetch the result row as an associative array. It will have column name(s) as keys, instead of numbers like 0, 1..; thus a clearer approach.

Now you have two options to get one-dimensional array of a particular column values.

Access the column value from the result row, using the **columnname** as key:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row['columnname'];
}
```

OR,

You can prepare the two dimensional array at first (as you may have multiple column(s)); and then use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function to fetch a particular column values as one-dimensional array.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}

// Extract values for a columnname key
$columnname_values = array_column($array, 'columnname');
```

OR,

Another alternative as suggested by *Nigel Ren* in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022786/php-unintentional-multidimensional-array-insted-of-onedimenisonal/53022945?noredirect=1#comment92948284_53022945), is to use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) function.

```
$array =  mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Extract values for a columnname key
$columnname_values = array_column($array, 'columnname');
```

Comment: With the second method you could also use `mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)` as it saves the loop.